Error loading .rb file in /lib after migration from rails 3 to rails 7
I have a very old application written with rails 3 and need to update it to current rails 7.
I am stuck with a  strange problem: in lib/assets there is a file tools.rb full of functions used across all models.
First I had to move tools.rb from "lib/assets" into "lib"
require "matrix"

def first_function(t,p1,p2)
  <snip>...</snip>
end

...

def last_function(t,p1,p2)
  <snip>...</snip>
end

Now, invoking any of these functions results in the following error:

expected file /home/daniele/src/sp4ct/lib/tools.rb to define constant Tools, but didn't

Then if I reload the same page a second time the error does not occurr anymore...
No idea of what is happening

Let me understand where are you coming from. A file that only defines functions is NOT autolaodable. It was not either before in Rails 3. Two questions: In Rails 3 how did the app load the file? And 2), is lib in the autoload paths?

Thanks for answering. First I have to apologize because I wrote Rails3 but it is 4.2. "...how  did the app load the file?" -> I use require "tools" in models._ "Is lib in the autoload paths?" -> I have "config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]" in application.rb

There are several things to fix in here.
First, the file is in the autoload paths but it is not autoloadable because it does not follow the conventions (it does not define Assets::Tools).
This configuration
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/

is not correct, autoload paths represent root namespaces, so Rails puts app/controllers in the autoload paths, but you don't put app/controllers/admin in the autoload paths because that is a subdirectory that represents the Admin namespace.
Please delete that line.
Rails 7.1 defines autoload_lib, which is more convenient, but in Rails 7.0 you can still do the following in its place:
lib = "#{root}/lib"
config.eager_load_paths << lib

# Ignore directories that do contain autoloadable .rb files.
Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(
  "#{lib}/assets",
  "#{lib}/tasks",
  "#{lib}/tools.rb" # you can restore the file in its original place
)

Then, in your models require "tools" as the application did before.

I used your code and now all is working as usual. So now the right way to go is eager loading. Thank you

No, no, config.eager_load_paths is a (not very intuitive) way to configure a directory to be both autoloadable and eager loadable. Same as app/models, say. The important bit is that we tell the autoloader to ignore lib/tools.rb because it does not define Tools.

So should i haveto change tools.rb to define a Tools class wrapping all its methods then change each call in all models to invoke Tools.myFunction(p1,p2...)

You do not have to, but that could be a good idea because the methods would live in a namespace instead of in top-level one, and because that way the file would be autoloadable and reloadable (in development mode, changes to lib/tools.rb would be reloaded). This could have been done in the previous version of the application too. Your call :).
